# jQuery form Validation error, no response

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   jquery validation
  </title>


 </head>
 <body>

  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/additional-methods.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#frmName').validate({
     rules:{
        field1:{
            required:true,
            lettersonly:true
        },
        field2:{
            required:true,
            email:true
        }
     },
     submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false;}  

    });
  });
 </script>

 <form name="frmName" id="frmName" action="" method="post">
  Enter name:<input type="text" name="field1"></br>
  Enter E-Mail:<input type="text" name="field2"><br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I have a little problem with jQuery Validation plugin.

Why is this validation is not working? Is this because of the wrong library I linked to?  I don't really understand whats wrong, so I decided to paste the whole validate script. Please take a look at my code.

Answer (score 2):

Your code working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KW6YZ/)

**It seems.you forget to add Jquery library**

Add bellow line top of the others libraries

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```